# Import java file on Nativescript

Tags: java, android, import, nativescript

I haven't been able to import or call .java files placed into platforms/android.. corresponding java folder where also tns activity and so on is.

I have tried something like `package.name.MyClass` and non seems to work. So my problem is calling java files to use in javascript.

Comment: Sharing my code which is completely unrelated to this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that java file in class path and then you may need to invoke class by

```
 public static Class<?> forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)
```

Comment: Where do I really need to put my .java classes and then how do I call them in javascript code?

Comment: Java is a server side language, whereas javascript is a client side language. Both cannot communicate. If you have setup some server side script using Java you could use AJAX on the client in order to send an asynchronous request to it and thus invoke any possible Java functions. 


Otherwise use applet and then call java function from there.

Comment: in NativeScript there is way to call java code with javascript code and it's mobile cross-platform programming :) so applet cannot be used too. @Terhoraj java files can be placed in platform but be careful to not delete platform folder if you haven't backup of them in case u clean platform

Comment: "Java is a server side language," 

> Unless its, like, an applet in a browser.


"whereas javascript is a client side language." >

Unless its, like, you know, nodejs.

Someone needs to catch up on technology, the 90s are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your code inside java class but for test purpose i did something like this

Content of java file inside `platforms\android\src\main\java\com\tns\JavaTestCall.java`

```
package com.tns;

public class JavaTestCall  {
   public String TestCall(){
       return "testCallString";
   }
}
```

JS code for test, somewhere in app code:

```
var JavaTestCall=new com.tns.JavaTestCall;
console.log(JavaTestCall.TestCall());
```

and in cmd/terminal you should see something like `JS: testCallString`

Comment: This starts to be promising! if this works I can try out some features that my java class provides. Then I only need to make this a plugin. I actually am working with plugin but calling .jar with package name and classes inside that fails. Always undefined :/

Comment: Mostly what you are looking are aar files what you will need to call then is only package name and name of class  but for how to do aar file better look somewhere on SO dont remember process but can be done with android studio :) if you have source code but not sure never tried use jar files

Comment: Or maybe what will be enough if you find package name and class name for those files inside jar